# TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Alembic's autogenerate keeps throwing this error and it's rather mysterious to me:

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/bin/alembic", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 581, in main
    CommandLine(prog=prog).main(argv=argv)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 575, in main
    self.run_cmd(cfg, options)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/config.py", line 552, in run_cmd
    fn(
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 214, in revision
    script_directory.run_env()
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 489, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 98, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 184, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 855, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/alembic/env.py", line 84, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/alembic/env.py", line 78, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/environment.py", line 846, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/runtime/migration.py", line 511, in run_migrations
    for step in self._migrations_fn(heads, self):
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/command.py", line 190, in retrieve_migrations
    revision_context.run_autogenerate(rev, context)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.py", line 444, in run_autogenerate
    self._run_environment(rev, migration_context, True)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.py", line 483, in _run_environment
    compare._populate_migration_script(
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/compare.py", line 25, in _populate_migration_script
    _produce_net_changes(autogen_context, upgrade_ops)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/compare.py", line 50, in _produce_net_changes
    comparators.dispatch("schema", autogen_context.dialect.name)(
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/langhelpers.py", line 303, in go
    fn(*arg, **kw)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/compare.py", line 75, in _autogen_for_tables
    [(table.schema, table.name) for table in autogen_context.sorted_tables]
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/util/langhelpers.py", line 230, in __get__
    obj.__dict__[self.__name__] = result = self.fget(obj)
  File "/home/mas/projects/icc/icc2-backend/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/alembic/autogenerate/api.py", line 362, in sorted_tables
    result.extend(m.sorted_tables)
TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable
```

My models are thus:

```
# app/models/mixins.py
from app import db

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr, as_declarative

@as_declarative()
class Base(db.Model):
    """This Base class does nothing. It is here in case I need to expand
    implement something later. I feel like it's a good early practice.

    Attributes
    ----------
    id : int
        The basic primary key id number of any class.

    Notes
    -----
    The __tablename__ is automatically set to the class name lower-cased.
    There's no need to mess around with underscores, that just confuses the
    issue and makes programmatically referencing the table more difficult.
    """
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()
```

```
# app/models/annotations.py
from datetime import datetime as dt

from app import db
from app.models.mixins import Base

class Annotation(Base):
    bookid = db.Column(db.Integer)
    author = db.Column(db.String)

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    edits = db.relationship('Edit', back_populates='annotation')

    HEAD = db.relationship('Edit',
                           primaryjoin='Edit.annotation_id==Annotation.id',
                           uselist=False)

    def __init__(self, book, author, start, end, text, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created = dt.now()
        self.bookid = book
        self.author = author
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.edits.append(Edit(author, start, end, text))


class Edit(Base):
    annotation_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('annotation.id'),
                              index=True)
    text = db.Column(db.Text)
    editor = db.Column(db.String)

    start = db.Column(db.Integer)
    end = db.Column(db.Integer)

    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    annotation = db.relationship('Annotation', back_populates='edits')

    def __init__(self, editor, start, end, text, *args, **kwargs):
        self.editor = editor
        self.start, self.end = start, end
        self.text = text
        self.created = dt.utcnow()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And because I'm not sure if it's relevant, my `alembic/env.py`

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

import os, inspect, sys
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.insert(0, parentdir)

from config import Config

config = context.config # alembic

config.set_main_option('sqlalchemy.url', Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
print(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)


# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)


from app import db
target_metadata = db.MetaData

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

The code is all at https://github.com/anno-wiki/icc2-backend if that might help. I'm hoping someone might be able to shed some light on this. Alembic's code is rather abstract and difficult to follow to see why that particular line is having trouble with my configuration. I've used a Base mixin plenty of times before and it's never been a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by changing `target_metadata = db.MetaData` to `target_metadata = db.metdata` fixed the problem, though then the models weren't detected. Importing app.models.Annotation and using `Annotation.metadata` made the whole thing work.